# Application.Exit and End diffrence

Tags: vb.net

Can you explain briefly what is difference here? I just noticed when i use End then immediately my entire application is shutting down. What is Application.Exit then do and what's difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
The End statement calls the Exit method of the Environment class in the 
System namespace. Exit requires that you have UnmanagedCode permission. If you 
do not, a SecurityException error occurs.
```

reference: [`End` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wt87xba.aspx)

Effectively, `End` calls `Environment.Exit` which is immediate termination of the program. Whereas, `Application.Exit` processes pending messages before shutting down.

[`Application.Exit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
Informs all message pumps that they must terminate, and then closes all 
application windows after the messages have been processed.
```

Comment: refering to your answer. In the end does both do the same? Second question does Applciation.Exit raise some event i can use to do some cleanup before exit?

Comment: No, both dont do the same thing. `End` calls `Environment.Exit` which is different from `Application.Exit`. [`ApplicationExit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event could be what you are looking for cleanup.